# codeblocks 20 can't detect g++.Even though It's inside MinGW inside CodeBlocks files and added to PATH.How can I link them?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, codeblocks

I'd been using CodeBlocks 17.02 but now I need c++14 plus support.
I tried installing codeblocks 20 which comes with latest MinGW compiler.
Problem is the IDE can't detect the compiler though it comes together, tried setting it from IDE compiler settings too. I tried adding the compiler to PATH. The compiler works fine from command line.How can I link them properly?(When latest MinGW is added to CodeBlocks 17.02, even it can't detect the compiler)
How can I use MinGW with c++17/c++14 support?

Comment: Define "latest". If it doesn't have GCC9.3 (C++17 and a lot of C++20), it's not the latest.

Comment: you know what I meant. The one that comes with codeblocks 20. Probably 8.something. Do you have answer to my quest?

Comment: Please include the images of Settings dialog box of Compilers and the compiler flags.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Codeblocks version 20 and then an error appears with the words "environment error can't find executable compiler". then I change the compiler settings as shown. and codeblocks can be run. my friend also experienced the same error. it could be that there is an error when installing codeblocks version 20 because it was just released.[codeblocks20.03.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2moEx.png)